# Apache downloading php files instead of executing them

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-server

I am trying to install phpmyadmin in my Ubuntu Server and when I try to access via browser to it, a php file downloads instead of displaying the web page. I placed a phpinfo testfile in /var/www and it is working fine.

I have already commented lines in php5.conf file:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
   # Deny access to raw php sources by default
   # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
   # only in specific virtual host or directory
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
  # Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
<FilesMatch "^\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml|ps)$">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default
#
# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it
#<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
#        php_admin_value engine Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

I am using Apache/2.4.6 and Ubuntu Server 13.10

Comment: we need more info: is it a vhost, a subdirectory ? Give us the config of the phpmyadmin path in apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed phpmyadmin as application, then try to download source code from official website and run it manually (copy into your directory /var/www and add VirtualHost settings in apache config ) It's easier than try to decide your issue.

Comment: Did this and worked correctly, I knew that the problem was something related to the installing path, seems that Apache is not allowing me to executing php scripts outside of my /var/www folder. But this works for me right now, thanks!